# Saving value passed with variable as numeric value instead of string value

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I wrote a custom search for finding items:

```
items: function() {
    var location = Session.get('location');
    var category = Session.get('category');
    var title = Session.get('title') || '';
    var minPrice = Session.get('minPrice') || '0';
    var maxPrice = Session.get('maxPrice') || '500';

    // some if/else if statements for client-side search inputs (no problem with these) 
    return Items.find({status: 'active', "title":{$regex: (title)}, location: location, category: category, "perDay":{"$gte": minPrice, "$lte": maxPrice}});

    //problem part is: "perDay":{"$gte": minPrice, "$lte": maxPrice}

}
```

The problem is, it doesn't show the right results for min-max amounts. The rest works fine.

IE: I put between 0 & 55, and it returns the item with 550. I put between 0 & 6 to 9, it still returns the item with 550. It looks like it matches the first numbers or something like that. When I type 549 to maxPrice, it doesn't return that item. 551 returns.

What am I doing wrong here?

**EDIT:**

As mentioned in comments, it was saved as string in DB. Now the problem is, I pass it as variable to my server method like this:

```
addItem: function(title, description, featured, category,location, perHour, perDay, perWeek, owner){     
    Items.insert({
        title: title,
        description: description,
        featured: featured,
        category: category,
        location: location,
        perHour: perHour,
        perDay: perDay,
        perWeek: perWeek,
        owner: owner,
        createdAt: new Date(),
        status:'active'
    }); 
}
```

and it saves the perDay field like this: "perDay": "35"

How can I make it save numeric?

Comment: Your values are most certainly "strings" and not numeric. That is why "550" would not be considered greater than "55" and even less than "60" in a lexical sense.

Comment: @BlakesSeven I think I understand but don't know how to fix the issue. Could you please explain/give an example/write an answer? Thanks!

Comment: As BlakesSeven said, this is a schema issue. @Luna, you have to take care while inserting data. For Example, while inserting perDay field, dont insert it like - {'perDay' : '500'} instead insert like - {'perDay':500}. This will insert your field as numertic and thus your same query will work fine.

Comment: @Abie I understand and you guys are right but I don't know how to save it as numeric field... I updated my question. Could you please take a look and answer if possible? Thanks

Comment: are you using any client to use mongodb? That client can help you edit your mongodb document.

Comment: or you can fire update query on your document as below:
update({find query}, {$set:{'perDay':'500}})
This will update your 1 document only. You have to correct all documents of your collection. Then you can fire your search query  which you mentioned at the top.

Comment: @Abie I actually updated previous documents (using mongol) and found how to pass the variable as numeric value like this in my event: var perDay = Number(event.target.perDay.value); - Can you please write an answer so that I can accept your answer? Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95775/discussion-between-abie-and-luna).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a schema issue. @Luna, you have to take care while inserting data. For Example, while inserting perDay field, dont insert it like - {'perDay' : '500'} instead insert like - {'perDay':500}. This will insert your field as numertic and thus your same query will work fine.

On your existing data you can fire update query on your document as below: `update({find query}`, `{$set:{'perDay':'500}})` This will update your 1 document only. You have to correct all documents of your collection. Then you can fire your search query which you mentioned at the top.

Answer (score 1):

For case insensitive search use below snippet:

```
{ 'title' : { $regex : title, $options: 'i' } }
```

You have to provide option for case-insensitive search.